# Business Partner not getting Created - Adempiere

Tags: erp, adempiere

I just deleted some of the fields of the Business Partner Window by logging in through System Administrator and now when I created fields again , and set their alignment , i need to enter the Search key Manually.

It doesn't fills automatically like before, If i just proceed with blank search key i get the following error:

> -----------> MBPartner.saveNew: [POSave_31778910-6af9-4ff2-8736-0335ea702a4f]
>   Not inserted - C_BPartner[12]
>   -----------> GridTable.saveWarning: SaveErrorNotUnique - ORA-00001: unique constraint (E2DEVELOPMENT.C_BPARTNER_VALUE) violated

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, the problem was due to deletion of all fields on tab and creating them again, the ad_sequence got corrupted. Once the ad_sequence was updated from backend Oracle the Business Partner started working fine again.